# "Undefined variable" error in shell script on Sun Grid Engine

Tags: sh, gridengine

I have the following Sun Grid Engine submission script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# sun grid engine cluster

# use current working directory
#$ -cwd

# merge error output into standard output stream
#$ -j yes
#$ -o generate_databases.log

# request to  cpu number
#$ -pe make 4

currentdir=`/bin/pwd`
echo "current working directory: $currentdir"
```

And here is my output

```
/home/eamorr/sge
currentdir: Undefined variable.
```

As you can see, the 'currentdir' variable returns undefined.

How to fix this?

Comment: Your sure that `/bin/pwd` is correct? Does it work when invoked manually?

Comment: The fact that the script output the current directory (`/home/eamorr/sge`) suggests that it is finding `pwd`. And, even if not, it shouldn't cause this error; `foo=\`/no/such/command\`` should still either assign a null string to `foo` or abort the script.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's bash? The backtick operator is not portable. There are several ways to (possibly) fix this:

1. use `#!/bin/bash` in the first line to make dure it's bash not anything else
2. avoid the backticks: `currentdir=$(pwd)` or `currentdir=$(/bin/pwd)`
3. or even simpler `currentdir=$PWD`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I'm not sure it's bash... I tried `currentdir=$(/bin/pwd)`, but it returned `Illegal variable name`

Comment: So it's most likely not bash. Try option (1) then, but actually, it probably uses a proprietary SUN shell which just behaves completely different from other known shells.